# Are there any microcontroller's that support MIPI-CSI2?

Tags: microcontroller, camera, image-sensor, mipi

As the title states; are there any microcontrollers that support MIPI-CSI2 on the market?

I know product recommendations are not allowed as part of the stack exchange so I will clarify a little further; if there are no MCU's that have MIPI-CSI2 communication interface (besides the soon-to-be released ESP32-P4 that I can find), I would like to understand the bottle neck?

Many SoMs and MPUs have this capability, but not many, if any, MCUs do. Is this because they need large supporting electronics such as RAM, or a dedicated DSP?

My application requires a single 4K frame to be captured, I do not need to record, nor have a processing time frame requirement and much of the information online as we have flowed into machine vision is now tailored toward the video capture market (e.g. This chip is capable of 1080p 30fps!). Does this mean this chip would be capable of a single 4K frame?

Appreciate any insight into the limitations and considerations of hardware so I am able to narrow my search to an ideal part. I don't want to run a whole MPU to capture a single frame every hour.

Comment: https://www.elektormagazine.fr/news/le-premier-microprocesseur-dote-d-une-interface-de-camera-mipi-csi-2-et-de-fonctionnalites-audio-avancees https://www.microchip.com/en-us/about/news-releases/products/new-1ghz-sama7g54-is-the-first-single-core-mpu-with-mipi-csi-2

Comment: https://www.mouser.be/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology/SAMA7G54-V-4HB?qs=W%2FMpXkg%252BdQ7%252Bk0TJiBz1%252BA%3D%3D&_gl=1*nx71c8*_ga*MTk4NTY1MDc4NS4xNjkzOTA2OTA5*_ga_1KQLCYKRX3*MTY5MzkwNjkwOS4xLjAuMTY5MzkwNjkwOS42MC4wLjA.*_ga_15W4STQT4T*MTY5MzkwNjkwOS4xLjAuMTY5MzkwNjkwOS4wLjAuMA.. https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/EV21H18A

Comment: Microchip SAMA7G5 Series -  [product page](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/SAMA7G54) and 
[datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAMA7G5-Series-Data-Sheet-DS60001765A.pdf) - 3070 pages ! || They say "The SAMA7G5 integrates complete imaging and audio subsystems with 12-bit parallel and/or MIPI-CSI2 camera
interfaces up to 8 Mpixels, up to four I2S, one SPDIF transmitter and receiver and a 4-stereo channel audio sample
rate converter."

Comment: [This](https://community.nxp.com/t5/Rapid-IoT/Are-there-any-low-power-consumption-MCU-which-support-MIPI/td-p/935824) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The NXP IMXRT117x Microcontroller with an ARM M7 @ M4F CPU running simple RTOS like FreeRTOS or Zephyr or barebone C has a 2-lane MIPI CSI2 camera interface if you don't want to use a Microprocessor running Linux, etc.